# Spring boot AMQP Concurrent listeners execute sequentially?

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp

I have a Spring AMQP listener defined like this :-

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "spring-boot-durable", concurrency="10")
public void recieve(String message) {
   ....some code here
}
```

Now in rabbitmq management portal i am publishing 30 messages when the above service is down, and bringing the listener service up.

When i do this, the messages are executed sequentially (one by one) rather than parallelly (10 at a time) although i set the concurrency to 10 as shown in the above piece of code.

Any reason why this is happening and any fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are affected by the `prefetchCount` - by default it's 250 so all the messages are going to one consumer.

Reduce it to distribute across the consumers but I recommend keeping it higher than 1; otherwise it will hurt performance.

Comment: is this a special case for when all messages are consumed at once? Concurrency works fine if the listener service is up and running when the messages are posted. Messages are consumed sequentially only when there are a lot of messages in the queue before the service is up.

Comment: No it's not a special case; it's only an issue when there are no consumers; when the first consumer starts, he gets up to `prefetch` messages, then the next consumer starts, then the next, etc. if you have 800 messages the first 3 consumers will get 250, the fourth will get 50. When there are active consumers, the broker distributes them automatically across all the active ones. Rabbit sees the `concurrency` as individual consumers, he knows nothing about the listener container and `concurrency`.

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you for your clear answer. :)